# How can i make sure that passing parameters don't have any cross site scripting contents

Tags: rest, spring-security, xss, html-encode

I am creating Rest Web services Using Spring & passing parameters to the method from model class.

My inputs parameters are as

```
{
    "user_id": 23,
    "user_email_id": "q@q.c",
    "user_password": "fdsdsdf",
    "firstname": "<script>window.alert(‘surprise!’);</script>",
    "lastname": "kdfgkdf",
    "mobile_number": "1414141414",
    "user_status": 1,
    "isdeleted": 0,
    "created_by": 1,
    "profile_picturename": "kfksdjfhksjd",
    "address": "sfdsdfsd"
}
```

& My ReST controller method is as

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/validate", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public Object AddUser(@Valid @RequestBody UserInputModel userInputModel, BindingResult br, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
    //Logic

}
```

Here i want to make sure that passing parameter dont contain any Xss or how can i make sure that HTML encoder will work for my input model

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Hibernate Validator's @SafeHtml annotation:

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.2/reference/en-US/html/ch02.html#validator-defineconstraints-hv-constraints

You need to add jsoup as a dependency

Example:

```
@Entity 
public class Foo {

  @SafeHtml(...)
  private String firstName;

}
```

Then if you validate the entity, it will be not valid if firstName contains xss